# pandas - add column with normalized selected values

Tags: python, pandas

I found some issues in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404387/pandas-get-values-from-multindex-columns) question, so I'd like to go a bit further. I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
H,Nu,City,L,C
0.965392,15,Madrid,es,es
0.920614,15,Madrid,it,es
0.726219,16,Madrid,tn,es
0.739119,17,Madrid,fr,es
0.789923,55,Dublin,mt,en
0.699239,57,Dublin,en,en
0.890462,68,Dublin,ar,en
0.746863,68,Dublin,pt,en
0.789923,55,Milano,it,it
0.699239,57,Milano,es,it
0.890462,68,Milano,ar,it
0.746863,68,Milano,pt,it
```

I would like to add a column called `Hm` defined as:

```
Hm = H/(H,City - where L==C)
```

So far I found the correct value / city with:

```
gp = df.groupby('City')
mask = gp.apply(lambda x: x['L'] == x['C'])
lookup = df.loc[mask[mask].reset_index(level=0).index]
```

obtaining:

```
     HmCity  Nu    City   L   C
5  0.699239  57  Dublin  en  en
0  0.965392  15  Madrid  es  es
8  0.789923  55  Milano  it  it
```

`H` values are now the correct values for the normalization. How can I now add a new column Hm so that the new dataframe is scaled in the corresponding positions of the `lookup`? As, for instance:

```
H,Nu,City,L,C,Hm
0.965392,15,Madrid,es,es,1,0
0.920614,15,Madrid,it,es,**
0.726219,16,Madrid,tn,es,**
0.739119,17,Madrid,fr,es,**
0.789923,55,Dublin,mt,en,**
0.699239,57,Dublin,en,en,1,0
0.890462,68,Dublin,ar,en,**
0.746863,68,Dublin,pt,en,**
0.789923,55,Milano,it,it,1,0
0.699239,57,Milano,es,it,**
0.890462,68,Milano,ar,it,**
0.746863,68,Milano,pt,it,**
```

I would like to avoid the `merge` because leads me to uncorrect behaviours.

EDIT:

to clarify: we can just add a new column `Hm` containing the corresponding HmCity values for each city as:

```
H,Nu,City,L,C,HmCity
0.965392,15,Madrid,es,es,0.965392
0.920614,15,Madrid,it,es,0.965392
0.726219,16,Madrid,tn,es,0.965392
0.739119,17,Madrid,fr,es,0.965392
0.789923,55,Dublin,mt,en,0.699239
0.699239,57,Dublin,en,en,0.699239
0.890462,68,Dublin,ar,en,0.699239
0.746863,68,Dublin,pt,en,0.699239
0.789923,55,Milano,it,it,0.789923
0.699239,57,Milano,es,it,0.789923
0.890462,68,Milano,ar,it,0.789923
0.746863,68,Milano,pt,it,0.789923
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your revised question, the following works for your particular dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[0.965392, 15, "Madrid", "es", "es"],
          [0.920614, 15, "Madrid", "it", "es"],
          [0.726219, 16, "Madrid", "tn", "es"],
          [0.739119, 17, "Madrid", "fr", "es"],
          [0.789923, 55, "Dublin", "mt", "en"],
          [0.699239, 57, "Dublin", "en", "en"],
          [0.890462, 68, "Dublin", "ar", "en"],
          [0.746863, 68, "Dublin", "pt", "en"],
          [0.789923, 55, "Milano", "it", "it"],
          [0.699239, 57, "Milano", "es", "it"],
          [0.890462, 68, "Milano", "ar", "it"],
          [0.746863, 68, "Milano", "pt", "it"]],
    columns=["H", "Nu", "City", "L", "C"])


def func(x):
    x['Hm'] = x.loc[x['L'] == x['C'], "H"].values[0]
    return x


print(df.groupby(["City"]).apply(func))
```

That gives the following output.

```
           H  Nu    City   L   C        Hm
0   0.965392  15  Madrid  es  es  0.965392
1   0.920614  15  Madrid  it  es  0.965392
2   0.726219  16  Madrid  tn  es  0.965392
3   0.739119  17  Madrid  fr  es  0.965392
4   0.789923  55  Dublin  mt  en  0.699239
5   0.699239  57  Dublin  en  en  0.699239
6   0.890462  68  Dublin  ar  en  0.699239
7   0.746863  68  Dublin  pt  en  0.699239
8   0.789923  55  Milano  it  it  0.789923
9   0.699239  57  Milano  es  it  0.789923
10  0.890462  68  Milano  ar  it  0.789923
11  0.746863  68  Milano  pt  it  0.789923
```

There may be a nicer way to do this though. I'll update the answer if I can come up with one.